# Are SMS messages queued or discarded when there's no signal?

Tags: sms, connection-issues

I'm thinking of getting an Android phone (a Samsung Galaxy S2) but I need to know whether it queues SMS messages (when there's no carrier) and then sends them when it's in signal again, or whether you have to re-send as on the iPhone. As I don't get a very good mobile signal at home this feature is very important for me.

Comment: Are you talking about text (SMS) messages?

Comment: Must be SMS (as the iPhone has no G-Voice nor Talk)

Answer (score 9):

This is a general Android question that applies to all devices.

Messages (SMS) are queued if there's no signal. See screenshot (device is in airplane mode).

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, Google Voice (which I use exclusively for SMS) added this feature recently.